# GlassFish, CDI and constructor injection

Tags: dependency-injection, glassfish, java-ee-6, cdi, constructor-injection

Is constructor injection supported in GlassFish 3.1's implementation of CDI for managed beans? I have a `@Singleton` EJB into which I want to inject another managed bean (contained in the same EJB module) using constructor injection. Field injection does work. But with constructor injection I get a `NullPointerException` from `AbstractSingletonContainer`.

This does work:

```
@Singleton
public class FooBean implements Foo {

  @Inject private BarBean bar;

}
```

This does not work:

```
@Singleton
public class FooBean implements Foo {

    private final BarBean bar;

    @Inject
    public FooBean(BarBean bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of glassfish? If this was not with 3.0.1, give it a try.

Comment: I think figured it out. The example is actualy working. It does only crash if the ear is already deployed when glassfish starts. After redeploying it works. Seems like a GlassFish bug to me.

Answer (score 10):

CDI does support direct field injection, initializer method parameter injection and constructor parameter injection. From the CDI 1.0 specification:

> ### 3.7. Bean constructors
>
> When the container instantiates a bean
>   class, it calls the *bean
>   constructor*. The bean constructor is
>   a constructor of the bean class.
>
> The application may call bean
>   constructors directly. However, if the
>   application directly instantiates the
>   bean, no parameters are passed to the
>   constructor by the container; the
>   returned object is not bound to any
>   context; no dependencies are injected
>   by the container; and the lifecycle of
>   the new instance is not managed by the
>   container.
>
> #### 3.7.1. Declaring a bean constructor
>
> The bean constructor may be identified
>   by annotating the constructor
>   `@Inject`.
>
> ```
> @SessionScoped
> public class ShoppingCart implements Serializable {
>     private User customer;
>
>     @Inject
>     public ShoppingCart(User customer) {
>         this.customer = customer;
>     }
>
>     public ShoppingCart(ShoppingCart original) {
>         this.customer = original.customer;
>     }
>
>     ShoppingCart() {}
>
>     ...
> }
>
> @ConversationScoped
> public class Order {
>     private Product product;
>     private User customer;
>
>     @Inject
>     public Order(@Selected Product product, User customer) {
>         this.product = product;
>         this.customer = customer;
>     }
>
>     public Order(Order original) {
>         this.product = original.product;
>         this.customer = original.customer;
>     }
>
>     Order() {}
>
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> If a bean class does not explicitly
>   declare a constructor using `@Inject`,
>   the constructor that accepts no
>   parameters is the bean constructor.
>
> If a bean class has more than one
>   constructor annotated `@Inject`, the
>   container automatically detects the
>   problem and treats it as a definition
>   error.
>
> If a bean constructor has a parameter
>   annotated `@Disposes`, or `@Observes`,
>   the container automatically detects
>   the problem and treats it as a
>   definition error.
>
> A bean constructor may have any number
>   of parameters. All parameters of a
>   bean constructor are injection points.

I wonder if your problem could be related to [WELD-141](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/WELD-141) though.

#### References

- CDI 1.0 specification

  - Section 3.7. "Bean constructors"
- Weld Documentation

  - [4.1. Injection points](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#d0e1107)

Answer (score 4):

Constructor injection is supported in GlassFish 3.x but you must provide a default constructor anyway to satisfy EJB specs.

This will work:

```
@Singleton
public class FooBean implements Foo {

    private final BarBean bar;

    public FooBean() {
      this.bar = null;
    }

    @Inject
    public FooBean(BarBean bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    } 
}
```

but Glassfish (this part is container dependant) **will call** the default constructor before the Injected one.

Comment: This will not compile as long as the variable `bar` is `final`.