# Constructor injection with wildfly 9 not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy a simple WAR file on wildfly 9.0.2 final.  The WAR has no web.xml and no EJB's for the moment - just, via annotations, a websocket endpoint with a dependency injection in the constructor and factories to produce the dependencies.  On deployment, I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.aip.textspace.infra.control.websocket.MainEndPoint.<init>
```

It looks like widlfly is trying to call a null constructor which does not exist. Here is the constructor for MainEndPoint:

```
@Inject
public MainEndPoint(SessionController control) {
    super();
    this.control = control;
}
```

I have another class called SessionControllerFactory which has a producer method for the injection:

```
@Produces
public SessionController build() {
...
```

In the Maven POM, I reference the CDI library:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

So what did I leave out that is needed for wildfly to call the constructor with dependency injection?

BTW, based on a [related response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541448/glassfish-cdi-and-constructor-injection), I tried adding a null constructor to MainEndPoint.  In that case the deployment succeeds but the injection never happens, and I get null pointer exceptions when accessiong this.control in MainEndPoint.

Comment: Can you provide more of the definition of your `MainEndPoint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason seems obvious: somehow `SessionController` hasn't been registered as a CDI bean.

Please make sure that in the following code:

```
 @Produces
 public SessionController build() {
    ...
 }
```

annotation `@Produces` states for  `@javax.enterprise.inject.Produces`, not `@javax.ws.rs.Produces` accidently.

Also please make sure that `SessionControllerFactory` is included in your war archive and **it is a managed bean class**.

BTW: you didn't mention anything about your `beans.xml` file (which is optional in WildFly 9 and in EE 7 in general). For the test purpose, you can add such file, set its attribute `bean-discovery-mode="ALL"` and check what happen.

Comment: I needed to make the factory classes (SessionControllerFactory and the factories needed for its contruction) @Singleton EJB's and add useless null constructors for them. Works perfectly now. No need for beans.xml, for the moment.